# Moq mvc controller with async ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I am trying to moq this Controller action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(decimal total, string from, string to)
        {

            decimal result = 0.00m;
            await Helper.GetEmployeeSalaryAsync(total, fromCurrency, toCurrency ,ConvertedValue =>
            {
                result = ConvertedValue;
                TempData["ConvertedResult"] = result;

            }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return View();
        }
```

using this test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void  Index_Should_Return_View_With_Converted_Currency()
{
    ActionResult resultView = null;
    decimal testToConvert = 110.00m;
    string from = "Home";
    string to = "Remote";


    var moq = new Mock<HomeController>();

    moq.Setup(x => x.Index(testToConvert, from, to))
        .ReturnsAsync(resultView)
        .Verifiable();
}
```

When I run the test I get this error "Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Index(.testToConvert, .from, .to)"}"

any idea how to properly set up a moc for this. I am trying to test the Tempdata["test"] existing and value.
Thank you

UPDATE:
All I needed to do is to test the Async ActionResult. Here is the final unit test

```
public async Task  Index_Should_Return_View_With_Converted_Currency()
        {

            decimal testToConvert = 110.00m;

            string from = "Home";
            string to = "Remote";
            HomeController controller = new HomeController();
         var  result = (ViewResult)  await controller.Index(testToConvert, from, to) ;

            Assert.IsNotNull(result.TempData["ConvertedResult"]);

        }
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to mock, and what are you trying to test? If you mock out the `Index` call, you're not going to be testing it...

Comment: @john, I am trying to Moq the controller and test the Index method.

Comment: But if you're mocking the controller, your *real* index method isn't going to be called at all... you'll just be calling the mock, which will return whatever you've told it to. You need to mock the *dependencies* of the code you're trying to test. (So in this case you might mock your helper.)

Comment: @John, you are 100% correct. I was having a brain fart late at night.
Only I needed to do was test the controller action without having to Moq anything.

Answer (score 1):

The method `Index` needs to be declared `virtual` otherwise the mocking framework cannot intercept it. This is a common limitation of mocking frameworks that use [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/). Rhino Mocks has the same problem, to get around it use dependency injection and pass objects around using interfaces as interfaces can always be mocked.

Is there an `IHomeController`? Then you just need to change this line:

```
var moq = new Mock<IHomeController>();
```